# generates the Delete query

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to write a query which generates the Delete query automatically based on the requirements. I will get To be deleted data from different tables and dump into temp table and then using this temp table I need to write query using IN operator, please suggest me, this is what I have tried.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @DeleteDisbursement TABLE (DisbursementId BIGINT, PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10),DisbursementAmount DECIMAL(19,4))
DECLARE @DeleteRecords Table(DisbursementId BIGINT,ActivityId BIGINT)
INSERT INTO @DeleteDisbursement (DisbursementId,PolicyNumber,DisbursementAmount) 
VALUES 
(4576,'12345',3.00),
(1232,'65455',143.44),
(2341,'34234',228.95),
(1111,'23155',414.89)

SELECT * from @DeleteDisbursement

DECLARE @GenerateScriptCount BIGINT =0
DECLARE @DisbursementIDValue BIGINT =0
DECLARE @ActivityIdValue BIGINT =0

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT Top 1 1 FROM @DeleteDisbursement)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @DisbursementId BIGINT =0
   DECLARE @PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10)
   DECLARE @AccountId BIGINT =0
   DECLARE @ActivityId BIGINT
   DECLARE @DisbursementAmount DECIMAL(19,4)

SELECT TOP 1 @DisbursementId =DisbursementId ,@PolicyNumber = PolicyNumber,@DisbursementAmount = DisbursementAmount
  FROM @DeleteDisbursement

SET @ActivityId = (SELECT ActivityId FROM ActivityLog WHERE ActivityAmount = @DisbursementAmount)  
  
  IF (@ActivityId > 0)
    BEGIN
      
     INSERT INTO @DeleteRecords (DisbursementId,ActivityId) VALUES(@DisbursementId,@ActivityId)
    
    END
  DELETE FROM @DeleteDisbursement WHERE DisbursementId = @DisbursementId

END
    
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT Top 1 1 FROM @DeleteRecords)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @DisbursementIDValue= @DisbursementId,@ActivityIdValue = @ActivityId FROM @DeleteRecords 

         PRINT 'DELETE FROM Disbursement Where DisbursementId IN (' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @DisbursementIDValue) +')' 

         PRINT 'DELETE FROM ActivityLog WHERE ActivityId IN (' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @ActivityIdValue) +')'  

        DELETE FROM @DeleteRecords WHERE DisbursementId = @DisbursementId

    END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

But its not working, Please help me How do I write query only 1 query which included in IN Operator like below :-

```
DELETE FROM Disbursement Where DisbursementId IN (4576,1232,2341,1111)
DELETE FROM ActivityLog WHERE ActivityId IN (1000,2000,3000,4000)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this row by row, and not just a single statement? Its a bit unclear if your @tables are just for demonstration purposes or if they're hard tables in your actual work.

Comment: I want to I am trying to achieve - I have created Temp table, in that table I have inserted all the records which I want to delete based on INPUT value (input might be 1000 records or more ). Using this temp table now I have to Generate Delete query with IN operator dynamically like (Delete * from table1 where disbId IN(1,2,3,4,5,6 etc till 1000 rows)) , this is basically for Performance purpose, I can able to achieve using = like (Delete * from table1 where disbId =1, Delete * from table1 where disbId =2 etc..) , but its taking very long time in Prod, so I have to achieve using only IN

Comment: So my query will just do the Print operation so manually I will copy the Print Generated query and will place to Production for DELETION purpose

Comment: Kindly suggest me how do I do PRINT with my above condition , I need to PRINT all value which i need to be deleted using IN operator  like PRINT ' DELETE FROM Disbursement Where DisbursementId IN (DisbursementIDValue)'

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't answering your direct question, but I am pretty sure it will be faster and avoid any of your problems. You will no doubt have to adjust to match your real-world version, but this should give the idea.

```
begin transaction

delete Disbursement
from DeleteDisbursement dd
join Disbursement on Disbursement.DisbursementId=dd.DisbursementId

delete ActivityLog
from DeleteDisbursement dd
join ActivityLog on ActivityLog.ActivityAmount=dd.DisbursementAmount

commit work
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, Basically my requirement is not Deleting directly like this, I need to PRINT the dynamically generated query like -  PRINT ' DELETE FROM Disbursement Where DisbursementId IN (DisbursementIDValue)' , here DisbursementIDValue may be like this 1,2,3,4,5 etc.. it should generate dynamically, I am not understanding how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this much complexity. You first store the values in temp table and reuse the temp table for your delete statement. or you can generate the id list using STRING_AGG function(supported from SQL 2017 onwards).

```sql
DECLARE @sqlStmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
CREATE TABLE #DeleteDisbursement (DisbursementId BIGINT, PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10),DisbursementAmount DECIMAL(19,4))
CREATE TABLE #DeleteRecords (DisbursementId BIGINT,ActivityId BIGINT)


INSERT INTO #DeleteDisbursement (DisbursementId,PolicyNumber,DisbursementAmount) 
VALUES 
(4576,'12345',3.00),
(1232,'65455',143.44),
(2341,'34234',228.95),
(1111,'23155',414.89)

INSERT INTO #DeleteRecords (DisbursementId,ActivityId) 
SELECT DisbursementId , ActivityId FROM ActivityLog AS al
INNER JOIN #DeleteDisbursement  AS dd
ON dd.DisbursementAmount =  al.ActivityAmount
'
```

- Approach 1 (Using Temp table for Id list)

```sql
SET @sqlStmt  += '

DELETE FROM Disbursement Where DisbursementId IN (SELECT 
DisbursementId FROM #DeleteRecords)
DELETE FROM ActivityLog WHERE ActivityId IN (SELECT 
ActivityId FROM #DeleteRecords)'

PRINT @sqlStmt
```

- Approach 2 (Id list generation using STRING_AGG)

```sql
SET @sqlStmt  += '

DELETE FROM Disbursement Where DisbursementId IN (' + SELECT STRING_AGG(DisbursementId ,',') FROM #DeleteRecords + ');'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
'DELETE FROM ActivityLog WHERE ActivityId IN (' + SELECT 
STRING_AGG(ActivityId ,',')  FROM #DeleteRecords+ ');'+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' 

PRINT @sqlstmt
```

Comment: Thanks venkat for your response, I tried your approach it did not work for me,  Because in my case I have to loop using while statement for inserting into @DeleteRecords table, because I will get the ActivityId  based on different condition as shown in my above query.  And I have tried adding the your approach 1 inside while it did not print